# android intent not activating

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

My intent to go to another android page isn't activating when i click the button.

My java code

```
public class CharSheets extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button Descrip, Atributes, Weapons, Skills, ACItems, Gear,
        Feats, SpecialAbilities, Spells;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.charsheets);
        setids();
    }

    private void setids() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Descrip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCharDescrip);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.bCharDescrip:
            Intent i = new Intent(CharSheets.this, CharDescrip.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.bCharAtributes:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(CharSheets.this, CharAtributes.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The XML mainfest

```
<activity
    android:name=".CharAtributes"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHARSATRIBUTES" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".CharDescrip"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHARDESCRIP" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I'm not sure what is causing the issue, but I have tried other solutions none of them have worked.  The way I'm doing it now I have used before and it has worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set an `onClickListener()` for you `Button`

```
private void setids() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Descrip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCharDescrip);
    Descrip.setOnClickListener(this);   // add this line
}
```

Now add your other `Buttons` here and use the `setOnClickListener()` for each in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't applied the `OnClickListener` to your button.

```
private void setids() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Descrip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCharDescrip);
    Descrip.setOnClickListener(this); // <--- This line is required.
}
```

As a side note it's common practice to name variables starting with lower case letters e.g. descrip

Answer (score 2):

You should set OnClickListener on your Button . . .

```
private void setids() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Descrip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCharDescrip);
        Descrip.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```